# Define a selector state in java

Tags: java, android, dynamic, selector

I would like to define a selector dynamically in java.

I use drawables from ressources and above I write some text. So, both normal drawable and drawable focus state cannot be defined into an xml file...

Is there a way to do this in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)?

This is the type of drawable that will be created by your selector.

So you could do something like this:

```
StateListDrawable drawable = new StateListDrawable();
drawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused}, mFocusedDrawable);
drawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled, android.R.attr.state_pressed}, mEnabledPressedDrawable);
drawable.addState(new int[0], mDefaultDrawable);
```